# Let $R$ be a Noetherian Ring, then the category of $R$-modules has enough injectives

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, injective-module

$R$ left-Noetherian, so all left ideals are finitely generated. I am trying to prove that the category of left $R$-modules has enough injectives.
That is, given any left $R$ module $M$, there is an injective map $M \to I$ with $I$ an injective $R$- module.

I imagine I want to apply Baers criterion but I don’t even know what object $I$ to consider in the first place!

Edit: I have shown that over a PID an $R$-module is injective iff it is divisible, using Baer’s criterion.

Comment: Are you talking about rings without identity maybe? It is well known that *all rings* (with identity at least) have enough injectives in their module categories.

Comment: Yep, $R$ has an identity. And of course you are right about the general case. I saw this question on an exam worth not many marks so I am presuming that the proof is easier when $R$ is Noetherian

Comment: I was not able to come up with an argument, but given that $R$ is noetherian, I would try to look at families of maps from $M$ to injectives (which are not necessarily injections), ordered by extension, and then try to show that a maximal element there necessarily is an injective function.

Answer (score 11):

Why not prove the general case directly? I think it is quite easy: firstly regarding $M$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module, for each nonzero $x\in M$, we may find a nonzero $\mathbb Zx\to\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ which extends to $f_x\colon M\to\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ as $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is $\mathbb Z$-injective. Then $M$ is embedded in $I:=\prod_{x\in M\setminus\{0\}}\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module. It follows that $$ M\simeq\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(R,M)\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(R, I),$$ where $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(R, I)$ is an injective left $R$-module, as $$\operatorname{Hom}_R(-,\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(R, I))\simeq\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(R\otimes_R-,I)$$ and $R\otimes_R-$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(-,I)$ are exact.

Comment: Sure, and $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ injective since its divisible right?  I was really just checking I wasn’t missing something obvious

Comment: @SEWillB Yes, being injective is equivalent to being divisible for a module over a PLID or a Dedekind domain.